# How to use one conditional formatting in Google Sheets to all sheets at once?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I made some 'conditional formatting' in Google Sheets for one sheet but I need to apply to others. There are about 45 tables and I really don't want to copy-paste it. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You can read and write conditional formatting with Apps Script. If you have problems with that, [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about the specific issues you encounter.

Comment: Another one crusader who fights for rules abidance. What's wrong with you dude?

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution would be to do the following:

- Record a macro of how you apply the conditional formatting on the first sheet
- Edit the macro so that it loops through each sheet (see code example below)
- Be sure to do this on a copy of the original sheet first in case there are any issues

Code:

```
function autoConditionalFormat() {
    // Counts how many sheets there are
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    numSheets = sheets.length;  

    // Loop to get name of each tab (sheet)
    var tabNames = new Array()
    for (var i=0; i<numSheets; i++) tabNames.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
        // Loops through each sheet
        for (var i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {
            // Applies some conditional formatting to each sheet
            SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(tabNames[i]));

            // Insert what your macro recorded here:
            var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
            var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
            conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp
               .newConditionalFormatRule()
               .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2')])
               .whenCellNotEmpty()
               .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
               .build());
           spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
               .setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
        }
    }
}
```